# Spring Boot 3 Multitenancy - Centrale database access

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant application using Spring Boot 3, where each tenant has an individual database and a central database is in place to manage tenants and their respective users. Basically, I dynamically switch data sources based on the tenant id extracted from the passed token if no id is found, default datasource (centrale database) will be set.
Given this configuration, tenants currently do not have the ability to manage their users. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to allow tenants to administer their users.

Comment: what is your data-access framework? as in Spring it is not so easy to switch database connection within JdbcTemplate, or Spring Data JDBC.....